Does Spring for GraphQL prefer WebFlux more than Web?
Many tutorials on the web seems to use Webflux than Web to build using Spring for GraphQL.  Does this mean the library is more tested/stable with Webflux than that of Web?
Thank you!

It would make sense to me due to webflux being non blocking and in graphql usually its like an orchestrator from various sources

I have an example project using Spring WebMvc, check https://github.com/hantsy/spring-graphql-sample/tree/master/spring-graphql-webmvc.
But this is only for HTTP protocol.
Spring for GraphQL also supports WebSocket and RSocket protocols based on the WebFlux stack, check the following example projects respectively.

https://github.com/hantsy/spring-graphql-sample/tree/master/spring-graphql-webflux
https://github.com/hantsy/spring-graphql-sample/tree/master/spring-graphql-rsocket-kotlin-co


The main spring for graphql tutorial on spring.io is using MVC https://spring.io/guides/gs/graphql-server Both MVC and WebFlux are supported equally.

I am not sure if the supported features are equal now when I checked it last time, the WebSocket protocol was not available in the WebMvc stack.

it is supported https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/reference/transports.html#server.transports.websocket
